# How can I get access to the descendants using Linq?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a .svg file that looks like this:

```
<g
 inkscape:label="Layer 1"
 inkscape:groupmode="layer"
 id="topLevelGroup">
<rect
   style="fill:#ff00ff;fill-opacity:1.0;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:1;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="rectPurple"
   width="60.0"
   height="30.0"
   x="60.0"
   y="90.0" />
<rect
   style="fill:#ffffff;fill-opacity:1.0;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1"
   id="rectWhite"
   width="90.0"
   height="30.0"
   x="30.0"
   y="130.0" />
```

So "g" is a group and there are more groups than just one, they have a unique id attribute each (here it's topLevelGroup). My task is to write a method that gets a group id as parameter and returns the colors of the rectangles that are in that group. For some reason I cannot gather these colors. Here's what I tried:

```
private IEnumerable<XElement> Groups => root.Descendants(ns + "g");
internal IEnumerable<string> GetColorsOfRectsInGroup(string id)
    {
        IEnumerable<XElement> spec_groups = Groups.Where(g => g.Attribute("id").Value.Contains(id))
                                                  .Select(g => g);

        IEnumerable<string> colors = from r in spec_groups.Descendants("rect")
                                     select r.GetFillColor();
        return colors;

    }
```

So basically I tried to first of all gather all the groups that match the parameter id, and then get the descendant "rect" objects and their colors. I don't get any error messages, it simply doesn't pass the test. Also here's the test method that checks this:

```
public void GetColorsOfRectsInGroup()
    {
        var colors = s1.GetColorsOfRectsInGroup("group1");
        Assert.True(UnorderedCompareSequences<string>(new string[] { "#ff0000", "#ffff00" },
            colors));

        colors = s2.GetColorsOfRectsInGroup("group2");
        Assert.True(UnorderedCompareSequences<string>(new string[] { "#00ff00", "#0000ff" },
            colors));
    }
```

I just started working with Linq today and I've been browsing sites but I can't figure it out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing the namespace at `Descendants("rect")`, should probaby be `Descendants(ns + "rect")`

Answer (score 1):

You should work more on [separation of concerns](https://nalexn.github.io/separation-of-concerns/). The reason that this is difficult for you is because you try to do everything in one big statement.

My advice would be to split your tasks into smaller tasks. This will not only make your tasks easier to understand and to unit test / debug, but, and that is a much bigger enhancement: it will make it easier to reuse your code for similar problems, or to adjust your coude for slight changes.

In this case, you should split your question into two subproblems:

- Read an SVG-file into a sequence of `Groups`, each with their zero or more `Rectangles`.
- Given the ID of a `Group`, give me the Colors of the Rectangles in the one and only  Group with this ID.

The advantage of splitting it into these subproblems is, that you can reuse the first method for other problems where you need to interpret the SVG file, for instance: "Give me all Group IDs", or give me the total surface area of all Rectangles of a Group.

The second procedure can reused if your input is not in an SVG file, but for instance in a List of "Groups with their Rectangles", or in a database.

Finally, it is easy to see that you can unit test them separately, which makes it way more easier to unit test edge conditions.

**Back to your question**

To read the SVG file, you need a class "Group with its zero or more Rectangles":

```
class Rect
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public double Width {get; set;}
    public double Height {get; set;}

    Color GetFillColor();
    ... // etc
}

class Group
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    ...

    // each group has zero or more Rects:
    public virtual ICollection<Rect> Rects {get; set;}
}
```

The reason that I chose to use an ICollection instead of a List, is because IMHO I think that `Rect[4]` doesn't have a defined meaning. `Rect["rectWhite"]` would have, but that is out-of-the scope of your question.

Another reason: this layout looks very much like the output from a database, like you would get from entity framework. If you later to decide to get your groups from database tables, you don't have to change this interface very much.

So you need a procedure to read you SVG file into a sequence of `Groups`. I'm not really familiar with SVG files, you'll probably know better how to use them than I know. Consider to use a NUGET package for this. So I'll focus on getting the colours of a Group.

```
string groupId = ...
IEnumerable<Group> groups = ... // fetch the groups from the source, in your case a SVG file

var result = groups.Where(group => group.Id == groupId)

    // from the remaining groups, get the FillColors of the Rectangles:
    .SelectMany(group => group.Rects,

        // parameter resultSelector:
        // from every group / rectangle combination, make one new object
        // containing the FillColor of the rectangle (so we don't use the group anymore)
        (group, rectangle) => rectangle.GetFillColor())

    // you might have duplicate colors; If you don't want them, use:
    Distinct();
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer was extremely helpful! I managed to understand how these things really work. Although I didn't use exactly your code, but with the help of it I succeeded to get it working on my own. Thank you very much again!

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;
            XNamespace ns = root.GetDefaultNamespace();

            string id = "rectPurple";

            List<XElement> Groups = root.Descendants(ns + "g").ToList();

            List<XElement> spec_groups = Groups.Where(x => x.Elements(ns + "rect").Any(y => (string)y.Attribute("id") == id)).ToList(); 
           
        }
    }
}
```